# Confusing riddle from paper calendar

Tags: pattern

Family member who knows I enjoy puzzles sent this and I can't figure out the author's intent here.

[image: December 3rd riddle]

Wondering if anyone here can decipher, or if it is just nonsense.

Comment: A solution is mostly visible in the image, though there is no context to determine if that solution is actually for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are meant to:

> Fill in the missing numbers so that the lines tell you how many of each digit appears on the page.

> When the answers are filled in, there will be ten digits in total on the page (excluding the 3 in "3rd").
>
>  So the numbers in the left-hand column must sum to ten.

> We need to place another 1 somewhere.
>  It can't go on the 3-line as we already have two 3's.
>
>  If it went on the 2-line, we could not have any more 1's or 2's, forcing us to have a three or greater on both the 3-line and 4-line. That would make the total too high.
>
>  So the missing 1 must go on the 4-line.
>
>  To make the sum to ten, we need the remaining unknowns to sum to five, so we must have five 2's and 3's in total.
>  We have three so far, so the missing digits must be a 2 and 3.
>  (We also cannot have any more 1's, 4's or 5's, so can only make the five as two+three.)
>
>  So there are two 2's and three 3's.

> And that gives us the following solution:
>
>  3 times 1
>  2 times 2
>  3 times 3
>  1 times 4
>  1 times 5

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, this seems like it.  Although, if we are considering the whole page it would have been better to include between the 6th and 9th of December instead of the 3rd...